# Can't connect to MySQL server on localhost (10061) on window 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7, mysql-error-2003

I am having window 7 as a operating system in the production machine where i am trying to use MySQL server 5.0 as a database. But i am unable to configure MySQL on my production machine. Following is the error i am receiving.

**The security setting could not be applied to the database because the connection has failed with the following error:**

Error no. 2003

 Can't connect to MySQL server on localhost (10061).

The message also prompts that you need to open TCP 3306 port to resolve this issue, i checked it and found that TCP 3306 port is already opened and state is listening.

This is my 'netstat -an' command result -

**Proto   LocalAddress           ForeignAddress         State**

 TCP       0.0.0.0:3306               0.0.0.0:0                      LISTENING

It means TCP at 3306 is open. Can anyone please tell me the solution of this problem. However i am able to install and configure the same MySQL Server setup in window xp. I tried google as well and found a lot of blogs but none is of use.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, certain firewalls can cause this error. Is this something you've checked?

Comment: Try to connect with telnet: `telnet localhost 3306`. If it fails, then probably firewall is blocking connections.

Comment: @kuri, Do you still have this problem? I have a similar problem after installation in Windows 7. I never tried MySQL on Windows XP. If you solved it, please post the answer here, and I can vote for you, if it is the solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
 host: localhost
```

to

```
 host: 127.0.0.1
```

This is likely caused by the way your database is being resolved.

Comment: where this property is set? as I am having same problem

"
Error no. 2003 
Can't connect to MySQL server on localhost (10061)."

and surprisingly only on clicking an specific table.

My database is connected, properly working but when I click on a specific table system throws this exception.

Comment: It's really dependent on that application you are using too connect to the database, but somewhere, you've definitely typed the connection string.

Comment: In the connection string you're using.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked whether the port 3036 is already in use by another application?
Have you checked whether a telnet `hostname` 3036 works on the local MySQL server and also on the remote machine?

Comment: yes i have checked, no the port is not in used by any other application

Answer (score 0):

First check in the system, MySQL services is in running condition or not.
look out on path of services go to right click on My Computer > manage > Services and Application > Services and check MySQL service status is started or not. Otherwise right click on service and start to service.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the **MySQL services** even after solving the problem.
I just run the `mysqld` as *administrator* and the problem is solved. So, simple but It took me 3 hours to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was rsolved.
The MySQL was not running in the Services section of Settings. Because XAMMP had disconnected the already running application in the background.